# How to test if part of a string is equal to an item in a list in python?

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to figure out how to test an item in a list with part of a string. so for example, if a list contains "potatoechips" and i have a string called "potatoe" how can I check if the string is found in an item in the list?

```
list = ['potatoechips','icecream','donuts']

if 'potatoe' in list:
    print true
else:
    false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `string.find(sub)` method to validate if a substring is in a string:

```
li = ['potatoechips', 'icecream', 'donuts']
for item in li:
    if item.find('potatoe') > -1:
        return True
else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 3):

To just test for presence of a sub string in any of the strings in the list, you can use [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
>>> li = ['potatoechips','icecream','donuts']
>>> s="potatoe"
>>> any(s in e for e in li)
True
>>> s="not in li"
>>> any(s in e for e in li)
False
```

The advantage is `any` will break on the first `True` and can be more efficient if the list is long.

You can also join the list together into a string separated by a delimiter:

```
>>> s in '|'.join(li)
True
```

The advantage here would be if you have many tests. `in` for millions of tests is faster than constructing millions of comprehensions for example.

If you want to know which string has the positive, you can use a list comprehension with the index of the string in the list:

```
>>> li = ['potatoechips','icecream','donuts', 'potatoehash']
>>> s="potatoe"
>>> [(i,e) for i, e in enumerate(li) if s in e]
[(0, 'potatoechips'), (3, 'potatoehash')]
```

Or, you can use `filter` if you just want the strings as an alternative:

```
>>> filter(lambda e: s in e, li)
['potatoechips', 'potatoehash']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if `'potatoe'` is in the list using `in`, but that will check if a specific item in the list is exactly `'potatoe'`.

Simply iterate over the list and then check:

```
def stringInList(str, lst):
    for i in lst:
        if str in i:
            return True
    return False
```

---

```
>>> lst = ['potatoechips', 'icecream', 'donuts']
>>> stringInList('potatoe', lst)
True
>>> stringInList('rhubarb', lst)
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using ['any'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and list [comprehensions](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html) to filter list to similar words.

```
list = ['potatoechips','icecream','donuts']
m = 'potatoe'
l = any(x for x in list if m in x)
print(l)
```